# Python 3.6+: Equality of two dictionaries with same keys but in different order

Tags: python

For two dictionaries `d1` and `d2` defined as

```
d1 = {'foo':123, 'bar':789}
d2 = {'bar':789, 'foo':123}
```

The order of the keys is preserved in Python 3.6+. This is evident when we loop through the dictionary and print the items.

```
>>> for x in d1.items():
...     print(x)
...
('foo', 123)
('bar', 789)


>>> for x in d2.items():
...     print(x)
...
('bar', 789)
('foo', 123)
```

Why does Python still consider `d1` and `d2` to be equal?

```
>>> d1 == d2
True
```

Comment: For backwards compatibility, among other things.

Comment: Dictionaries aren't semantically ordered data structures, *even if they retain insertion order*. If you want a semantically ordered dictionary, use `OrderedDict`  - `OrderedDict([("foo", 123), ("bar", 789)]) != OrderedDict([("bar", 789), ("foo", 123)])`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dictionaries are hash tables, order is not supposed to matter. In python 3.6+ dictionaries are in insertion order but that is just how they are implemented. Order doesn't matter for equality. If you want order to matter in equality use an OrderedDict.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d1 = OrderedDict({'foo':123, 'bar':789})
d2 = OrderedDict({'bar':789, 'foo':123})

print(d1 == d2) # False
```

Comment: In fact until Python 3.5, order of insertion was not maintained for `dicts`.. 
The fact that order of insertion is maintained can again change in any future version of Python

Comment: True though the odds of them doing that are slim since it would not be backwards compatibable. In 3.5 it was a implementation detail, in 3.7 it was official.

Comment: Yes - as of Python-3.7, it is [guaranteed by the language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744/984421) that `dict` maintains insertion order.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse It was an implementation detail in 3.6, not 3.5.

Comment: @ekhumoro yes what? The order is guaranteed but it doesn't change equality

Comment: @CervEd Yes nothing. I made no claims about equality. I simply provided a relevant link regarding language guarantees, since the answer still only states that insertion order is an implementation detail with some older versions of Python. Even so, the order ***can*** be used to test for equality like this: `list(d1.items()) == list(d2.items())`. So it's not necessary to use `OrderedDict`.

Comment: @ekhumoro why call `list`?

Comment: @CervEd It would be totally broken if `d1 == d2` did not equal `d1.items() == d2.items()`. So converting to `tuple/list` is required. (And also see the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58961159/984421) regarding backwards compatibility).

Comment: @ekhumoro right. Still, using an `OrderedDict` for this purpose is much more obvious and I don't see any drawback

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries were unordered up until Python 3.6. Therefore the only sensible way to test for equality was to ignore the order. When Python 3.6 ordered dictionaries this was an implementation detail. Since Python 3.7 the insertion order can be relied upon. But changing the behavior to only consider dictionaries only equal if the keys are in the same order would break *a whole lot* of code. And quite frankly I think it is more useful to compare dictionaries without taking the ordering into account.

Comment: Very true. I prefer order doesn't matter, it makes a lot of code easier.